# How to change a function/formula in a whole column where I also have empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba, worksheet-function

I have a column with a formula/function that has other cells as parameters. However in the column, every few rows I have a subtotal and blanks, for readability.
Now I decided to change the formula/function but I can not do copy+paste on the whole column because of the subtotals/blank cells, and I can not do change+replace because there are parameters in the functions that uses other cells and thus it is different in each cell in the column.

For example, if the formula is `=if(A5>24,1,"")` and I want to change it to `=AA_userfn(A5,B5)`

Any idea how to change it easily?
currently I copy+paste few rows at a time, but that is tedious.

Maybe a Sub that will go all over the column (the column number as an input parameter) and looks for `=if(`, and then replaces it with `=aa_userfn(Ax, By)` where `Ax` and `By` are calculated based on the position of the cell currently changed in reference to the previous values in that cell.

Any ideas will be welcomed

Answer (score 1):

Change to suit your needs

```
Public Sub UpdateFormula()
Dim r As Long, c As Long, n As Long, x As Long, a As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rngSlct As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Select the column you want to update. This can be multiple columns
Set rngSlct = Selection
With rngSlct
    x = .Columns.count
'Loop through all the selected columns
For n = 1 To x
    a = rngSlct(1, n).Column
lRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row
c = a

With ActiveCell
    For r = ActiveCell.row To lRow
        If Left(Cells(r, c).Formula= "=If(" Then
            Cells(r, c).Formula = 'Type your new formula here
        End If
    Next r
End With

Next n
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```